# When to set MenuItem intent or to Start activity in onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-menu

Just started to understand android and bumped into ways on starting activities on a MenuItem. I'm wondering when should I set a MenuItems' intent and let it start the activity or to call startActivity when a MenuItem is selected.

```
// Call this in onOptionsItemSelected when an item is selected;
private void startSomeActivity() {
    Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=someaddress");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoLocation);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        startActivity(intent);
}

vs

// Call this in onCreateOptionsMenu and set intent of items.
private Intent getSomeIntent() {
    Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=someaddress");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoLocation);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        return intent;
    return null;
}
```

It seems that both are working the same way. Thanks.

Comment: both are the same, you can use what you wants and works like charm

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches result the same but the second one is an opimized one to reduce the efforts of calling startActivity() method agin and agin on menu Item selection.